BQ load_table_from_file support for Columns with special characters
I'm trying to inject some data through load_table_from_file in Python but when I do some column is all null when I query it after calling named function. Is there a way to support special characters through this function?
A little context: I'm transforming a Pandas DF into a parquet file buffer in order to load the info to BQ.
Things I've tried, round name with backticks in the DF before writing the parquet file e.g `column_name+` with no luck.
Here's the DF showing non-null data

And here's the result after injecting into BigQuery

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Have you tried inserting data directly from the panda as dataframe? can you  try again after giving the schema directly in the code? Let me know if it helps?

In this case I do need to be a parquet due to performance issues in the past. Anyway, loading directly the df needs the df to have All columns specified in the table schema and this is not very common in my case, unfortunately,

Yes, the parquet file format gives better performance. Could you try injecting data into the bigquery table after renaming the column name?

I tried that, yes. It is totally the special character. I think at this moment it is better to rename the column schema instead of trying to support it as it is right now.
